# Avada Layout builder

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress with Avada theme for my website.
An Avada child theme has been created with a customization for a "services" post/category type in it and some css customization. See attached/below for contents of the Avada theme child folder.

I would like to see if I can use the Avada Layout builder itself to make these customizations instead. It would make me more flexible to do changes on the website myself in the future, since I am not so good with php.

However, in the Layout builder if i choose for the "services" archive layout conditions, no posts are shown. I think this has something to do with the fact that the post/category type has been created directly in php and not in Avada itself.

Anybody who can shine a light on this?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

[image showing file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x27oo.jpg)

I had a look at all php files in the theme child folder, but I am not sure what I have to change to be able to be able to show the services posts with the Layout Builder.

Answer (score 2):

Basically to show the posts, you need to use the **Archives Element** in the layout created for your category. Only **Archives Element** element or **Post Card Archives Element** can display posts if a post card has been established in your library of Avada.

Below are documentation links.

https://avada.com/documentation/archives-element/

https://avada.com/documentation/post-card-archives-element/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What we've done in this case is create blog post categories within Avada. When we post we use the standard format and have created a custom blog layout template that we call.

In that template, we can designate what categories show up in the 'blog posts' sections on the blog template.

I've never used the archives element and while that may be a better way to go about it, this technique has proven to be an effective way to categorize our content.

Hope this helps.

[image]